# Print from iPad without AirPrint or Wi-Fi

Tags: network, printing, ipad, cellular-data

Consider the following configuration

- I have a Wi-Fi iPad without 3G support.
- I also have an HP printer that doesn't not have Wi-Fi capabilities.
- My printer supports USB.
- I am planning to buy a 3G Wi-Fi Router.

I understand, in order to print from my iPad to a printer I need an AirPrint-compatible printer. I am also aware that for certain selected printers (let say mine is one of those privilege) you can use iOS Apps from OEM such that you can print from your iPad. But even to use it, I need a Wi-Fi enabled printer.

I am planning to purchase a 3G Wi-Fi router so that I can connect my iPad outside a Wi-Fi network.

Now from here I was wondering, if I can use such a 3G Wi-Fi router which suppose has a USB Port to connect my printer and provide me the option to print from my iPad?

**Note**
I am not sure if this question fits in Ask Different as my target device is an Apple Device but even then there is more than that this question would cover. So in case if you feel this question fits there, feel free to migrate.

Comment: you could also try various printing apps such as printcentral or print n share, these can work with non airprint printers for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased this router for around 20 dollars, and installed TomatoUSB to it. (Many routers support it, just make sure you find one that does):

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0045HG53K/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045HG53K)

And then followed these instructions to install AirPrint to the router:

http://blog.qnology.com/2013/03/tutorial-apple-airprint-on-tomatousb.html

I'm able to print from my iDevices that are on the wifi, my other computers on wifi, and that tutorial also includes instructions to install Cloudprint, through which I'm able to print from anywhere.

TomatoUSB will work with lots of routers, just make sure the one you want to buy will support it before you buy.

Comment: I believe this is the ideal solution for my purpose. I do not need to purchase a MAC in order to install AIR Print. It will just work with any Machine and Printer.

Answer (score 5):

To print to your HP printer using AirPrint you will need some kind of AirPrint server.  It is not enough to just get network connectivity to the printer, you need some software running somewhere to handle some of the communication details.  It is conceivable that someone makes a 3G WiFi router that includes AirPrint support but I think is unlikely.

Probably your best bet is to run AirPrint software on the computer that is connected to the HP printer so that computer can act as the AirPrint server.  You can get [NetGear Genie](http://www.netgear.com/about/press-releases/2012/05072012.aspx) for free (though I removed it because the version I used with the OS version I was running caused my computer to crash with kernel panics, but maybe that's fixed now) or something like [handyPrint](http://www.netputing.com/applications/handyprint-v4-1/) (never tried it).

Answer (score 1):

Use the HP App "HP ePrint" it works like a charm. First you must  connect the  HP printer to the router and share it on your network. "HP Printer Control" is also a nice App to add. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the app called PrintnShare on your iPad. Although it will print to all wifi printers, it will also print to your USB printer via your computer. Note the iPad does not support printing over a usb cable direct from the iPad to a printer. It will also support adhoc network and 3G printing.

Answer (score 0):

(not sure this kind of solution is of interest to the OP but it might be to someone).

If you have OpenWrt installed in your router, you can make it advertise and serve an old printer as an AirPrint capable printer by using these [packages](https://github.com/FranciscoBorges/openwrt-printing-packages):

- If you do not know what OpenWrt is, then perhaps that is not for you;
- btw, I am the author of the above OpenWrt package feed.

Answer (score -3):

If you don't have an AirPrint compatible printer you can use the app, Print Hub, which supports printing every filetype I've tried, has the option to connect to Dropbox, lets you edit photos before printing and it's only $0.99!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/print-hub/id612603224?mt=8

Comment: Are you in some way affiliated?

Comment: @Alex Might be, if he's the same "Jared" mentioned at http://slackshotindustries.blogspot.ca/2013/04/gotta-say-its-all-about-app-store-seo.html

Comment: @Jared You ought to be aware of the policy here about self-promotion. Affiliations **must** be disclosed.  Please see the bottom section of this page: http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior